# Surah Imran verse 146 vs Surah Baqarah verse 214

Tags: surat-al-baqarah, surat-al-imran, contradiction

As mentioned in the question, the verses mentioned are

**Surah Im'ran: Verse 146**

> And how many a prophet [fought and] with him fought many religious
>   scholars. But they never lost assurance due to what afflicted them in
>   the cause of Allah, nor did they weaken or submit. And Allah loves the
>   steadfast.

and 
**Surah Baqarah: Verse 214**

> Or do you think that you will enter Paradise while such [trial] has
>   not yet come to you as came to those who passed on before you? They
>   were touched by poverty and hardship and were shaken until [even
>   their] messenger and those who believed with him said,"When is the
>   help of Allah ?" Unquestionably, the help of Allah is near.

The question is that Surah Im'ran's verse mentions the fact that true believers and their prophets were **not** weakened when they faced adversities. However, Surah Baqarah mentions a slight counter-statement towards it by stating that prophets(together with their believers) were indeed **shakened** (*which is natural considering the adversities they faced*) and even got a "bit irresolute" when they cried out regarding the help of Allah. IMO both of these verses slightly contradict each other.

Am I missing any important context/commentary here?

Comment: "how many a prophet" is just that - "many" not "all".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no contradiction.

3:146 is saying that they did not give up hope, did not surrender, did not run away, and did not apostatize.

2:214 does not say that they did any of the above. Rather it says that they were shaken (زلزلوا i.e. afflicted) so much that they sought hastening of Allah's help. It does not mean that their resolve weakened or that they doubted.

Further reference:

Tafsir al-Qurtubi on [2:214](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura2-aya214.html#qortobi) and [3:146](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura3-aya146.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assalamo Alaikom and thank you for contacting our website.

Allah (SWT) says in verse (3:146)

> And how many a prophet [fought and] with him fought many religious scholars. But they never lost assurance due to what afflicted them in the cause of Allah, nor did they weaken or submit. And Allah loves the steadfast. (3:146)

And He says in verse (2:214)

> Or do you think that you will enter Paradise while such [trial] has not yet come to you as came to those who passed on before you? They were touched by poverty and hardship and were shaken until [even their] messenger and those who believed with him said,"When is the help of Allah ?" Unquestionably, the help of Allah is near.

There is no contradiction between the 2 verses, as in the second verse the fact that they (were shakened) in the battle from its intensity reflects their human nature, but does not mean that they (lost assurance) as they have a firm belief in Allah (SWT) and they trust that at the end He gives victory to true believers who follow His guidance, though they may face setbacks as they did in the Battle of Uhud for disobeying the orders of Prophet Muhammad, peace be upon him.

What counts is the end result, and though at times they went through adversities and defeat, this was not the last outcome.

Moreover,my Dear brother the definition of true believer is cleared by Allah in Surah hujurat

> The believers are only the ones who have believed in Allah and His Messenger and then doubt not but strive with their properties and their lives in the cause of Allah . It is those who are the truthful.(49verse 15)

And Allah knows best.

We hope you find this answer useful In-Shaa-Allah

May Allah (SWT) make all matters easy for you and guide us all to His Straight Path.

Ameen